# Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $Q=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in U\mid x_1=1\}$. Show that $Q$ is not open and $\partial Q=\emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $Q=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in U\mid x_1=1\}$. Show that $Q$ is not open and $\partial Q=\emptyset$.

To me it looks obvious, but how can I write a proof properly ?

This is my proof. Suppose that there is $x\in Q$ such that $\underbrace{B_x(\varepsilon)}_{=\{y:\|y-x\|<\varepsilon\}}\subset Q$ for a certain $\varepsilon>0$. In particular, all $y\in B_x(x)$ has to be of the form $(0,y_2,...,y_n)$, and thus it's not a ball of $\mathbb R^n$. So it's a contradiction.

It's not very clear. How can I do better ?

Comment: There is no guarantee that $Q$ will be closed in $\mathbb R^n$. Are you forgetting to mention a hypothesis on $U$ ?

Comment: In fact the question is "Q not open". Sorry for this mistakes @Justpassingby

Comment: But it *may* be the case that $Q$ is open (and closed). The example I have in mind also seems to be the *only* case where $\partial Q=\emptyset$.

Comment: If $U = \{(0, \dots, 0)\}$, then $Q = \emptyset$, which *is* open. This means that you must add some hypotheses on $U$, otherwise your problem is not correct.

Comment: Exactly, even the new problem cannot be addressed without additional hypotheses on $U$. Unless they mean relatively closed in $U$?

Comment: Sorry, $U$ is a neighborhood of $(1,...,1)$. @Justpassingby

Answer (score 1):

Every small neighbourhood of $(1,\ldots,1)$ contains points whose first coordinate is different from 1; hence the points whose first coordinate is 1 do not form an open set.

The boundary of that set is generally nonempty. For example take $U=\mathbb R^n$ then the set $Q$ is its own boundary.